# Converting a pure GitHub HTML website to Jekyll (Terminal Errors)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

My computer is a MacBook Pro with macOS Mojave. I am planning to serve my HTML webpages that already exist in GitHub repo with Jekyll.

I installed Homebrew, then I installed Rbenv to use a newer version of Ruby b/c I can't use the System Ruby in Mac OS. I installed Ruby version 2.5.0 through Rbenv, and typed:

```
gem install bundler jekyll
```

and when the installation ended successfully, it said it downloaded 26 gems. I already have a local file and several HTML files that are already added committed and pushed to my GitHub repository, so I entered:

```
jekyll new (repository-name)
```

but the terminal returned this error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand the reason the terminal cannot find any gem w/ executable jekyll.

What jekyll commands should I use to insert jekyll into my already-existing GitHub repository instead of making a new one?

Comment: Looks like your rbenv install didn't take, or you haven't switched into Ruby 2.5. What happens if you type `rbenv local` from the terminal?

Comment: It works fine; it says 2.5.0

Comment: OK, try `ruby -v` from the terminal.

Comment: It says ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Comment: Right. So your system doesn't know about the rbenv shims. Try restarting the terminal and then `ruby -v` again.

Comment: It still returns the same result; is there any way that I can make my computer know the 'rbenv shims'?

Comment: Yep. Per the [docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell), run `rbenv init` then restart your terminal.

Comment: hmm..still the same

Comment: OK. Again, per the docs, you should use this script to diagnose the problem: `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`